How do I fix this display issue on my website?
I am trying to make my practice website look neat and organized, but I encountered a couple of issues. The first one is that my Yugioh Picture is small, and doesn't fit the same scale and size of the magic the gathering picture above it. I have tried to change it's height and width, but it did not move an inch or change anything at all. Second, my Yugioh Card banner was unable to be moved to the left side of the website any further. It just stuck in one place.
Here's my CSS.
body {
  background-color: gray;
  }
.cards {
  position: relative;
  left: 430px;
  top: 50px;
  }
.movDetails {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  }
.movImage {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  }
.movIndexImages {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
  }
.hyperlink a {
  text-decoration: none;
  }
.movNav {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 90px;
  }
footer {
  background-color: rgb(217, 205, 205);
  color: white;
  }
.movTcg {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  height: 110px;
  }
.movDescription {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  }
.movSearchBar {
  position: relative;
  left: 350px;
  }
.movText {
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  left: 20px;
  }
.movBrowserBar {
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  }
.movHololive {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  left: 200px;
  top: 80px;
  }
.movMGT {
  position: relative;
  height: 190px;
  /* Not Working */
  right: 99900px;
  }
.movFooter {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;

  /* display:flex; */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }
.movPokemon {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  top: 90px;
  left: 680px;
  }
.movYugioh {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 990px;
  }
.movMagGlass {
  position: relative;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 0px;
  }
.refFlex {
  /* display: flex; */
  justify-content: flex-end;
  gap: 30px;
  /* Why is this refusing to be moved? */
  bottom: 50px;
  }
ul {                        /* Ul is whole box container containing ul. */
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  gap: 20px;
  }

/* Targets all li. Makes it seem like it forms a blue box, but 
 really all it is doing is making sure every li is 
 colored the set color. */

ul li {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  }
ul li a {  
  }
.items {
  display: flex;
  gap: 100px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
  }
section .movItems {
  }
section a img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  }
.item1 img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}

Here's my html:
<%- include('./partials/header.ejs')%>

<main>
  <div class="movDescription">
    <h1 style="color: red"> TCGCards.com </h1>
    <p> <b> Power to the People! </b> </p>
    <p>
      <b>A marketplace for trading card collectors, and players. Here, we have a great and varied selection of 
      trading card goods from all over the world! You will never find any better deals then this!
      </b>
    </p>
    <div class="movSearchBar">
      <div class="fixhyperlink li a">
        <!-- /cards means that you want to see something specific. -->
        <!--/cards/ means you want to see whole section.  -->
        <div class="movText">
          <a href="/cards">  Browse Our Collection </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="movIndexImages">
    <img src="/images/pokemon.jpg" alt="pokemon" class="movPokemon">
    <img src="/images/yugioh.jpeg" alt="yugioh"  class="movYugioh" >
    <img src="/images/magic-the-gathering-2-558x331(resized).jpg"  alt="MGT" class="movMGT">
  </div>
</main>

<%- include('./partials/footer.ejs')%>

I am also very confused why my footer is out of place.

I tried to get rid of any possible restrictions like display: flex for my picture banner area in order to fix earlier image issues since I read online that that could have caused problems, but that did nothing.


Try to avoid fixed units like px which tend to make layouts non-responsive. Use relative units like %, or probably better still in this case investigate flex and grid and size images with cover or contain.
